# Condition for $\|X_n^{-1}\|$ to be bounded?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, pseudoinverse

Let $\lambda_n = \|X_n^{-1}\|$, where $X_n$ is a non-singular $p\times p$ square matrix and $\|A\| = \sup_{|x| = 1}|Ax|$, with $|\cdot|$ the Euclidian norm. Is there a sufficient condition so that the following holds?

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \lambda_n < \infty$$

My intuition is that if the $X_n$ are uniformly nonsingular, i.e.

$$\exists \delta > 0, N;  |\det(X_n)| > \delta, \forall n > N$$

then indeed the statement is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *uniform nonsingular* is not a sufficient condition. See example below.

Consider the diagonal matrix $D_n$ having diagonal coefficients $(1/n,n, 1, \dots, 1)$. Then $D_n^{-1}$ is the diagonal matrix with coefficients $(n, 1/n, 1, \dots, 1)$.

Consequently:

1. $\vert \det D^{-1}_n \vert = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. In particular $D_n$ is not singular.
2. $D_n^{-1}e_1= ne_1$, where $e_1$ is the first vector of the canonical basis. Hence $\lambda_n \ge n$ and the sequence $(\lambda_n)$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you! If we make the additional assumption that $\|X_n\|$ is bounded, would that be a sufficient condition?

Comment: In that case (with the uniformly nonsingular condition), the answer is positive. The idea is to use the formula giving the inverse of a matrix based on the adjugate and the fact that on a finite dimensional real space, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: Neat! Except I'm not sure how to prove that the first minors themselves are bounded.

Comment: The minors are polynomial functions of $X_n$ coefficients which are all bounded if $X_n$ is bounded as all norm are equivalent in a finite dimensional space.

Comment: And the minors being polynomial functions of the elements of $X_n$ can be shown through the Leibniz formula, correct?

Comment: Minors are determinants. And determinants are polynomials of the coefficients.